# One liner to avoid using temporary variable with array.from?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```js
const data = [];
Array.from({ length: 1 }).forEach(() => {
  data.push({
    number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  });
});

console.log(data)
```

I use above code to generate array of object but I used data as temporary variable, not sure if I can write it better.

Comment: You might want to use `map` to put the result directly to `data` instead of updating `data` in `forEach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `forEach` invocation. [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) accepts a callback function as the second argument:

```js
const data = Array.from(
  { length: 3 },
  () => ({ number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) }),
);

console.log(data);
```